# Best way to restrict access to certain folders and it subfolders via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, server

What is the best way to restrict access to certain folders and it subfolders with .htaccess on site?

Is it good enough to redirect from domain.com/css to domain.com? 
If so, how implement this?

---

**Update**

The best way I found yet is code below in main .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To block access to a sub-directory called `folder`. Create a `/folder/.htaccess` with this line:

```
Deny from all
```

If you want to redirect every request of `/folder/` to `/` then use this rule in `/folder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=302]
```

Comment: So I must create in every single subfolder of some folder htaccess file? Is it really the best way of solving this issue?)

Comment: No) Doesn't work if create htaccess only in main folder. It redirects from domain.com/folder/subfolder to domain.com/subfolder

Comment: Oh, I'm talking about redirecting to main page) Not about Deny from all method

Comment: Yes, your code redirects, but it doesn't work for subfolders. It redirects from domain.com/folder/subfolder to domain.com/subfolder. And subfolder are still in url(

Comment: Yes, it works fine now! Could you tell me please one more thing? Is it possible to redirect all url requests to main domain? For instance, domain.com/somerequest/etc to domain.com. I mean, some universal rule   in main .htaccess file.

Comment: No, the thing is I have some landing page and want all chars after / will be redirecting to main domain)

Comment: You mean in main root .htaccess file? If so, it doesn't redirict now.

Comment: All right, thank you! The site has just one page, so there is only one url. And for defend purposes I want to redirect all requests after / to main domain :) Like so: domain.com/blabla123 redirects to domain.com

Comment: To rewrite everything to landing page use: `RewriteRule . / [L]` and to redirect use: `RewriteRule . / [L,R=302]` (both these rules need to be in DocumentRoot's .htaccess)